# jQuery - Change background-color on scroll

Tags: jquery, css, navbar, background-color, onscroll

I am trying to change the `background-color` (currently set at `transparent`) of my navbar on scrolling. I have tried lots of different things but it does not work. Please help me.

This is my current code

```
$(window).ready(function() {
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 300) {
     $(".navbar").css("background", "blue");
    } else {
     $(".navbar").css("background", "transparent");
    }
  })
})
```

ps. I don't think this can be the cause but I have built the website with Foundation. However, I have set the `background: transparent` using regular SCSS.

Comment: your code is ok. could you provide url or make some example?

Comment: ` but it does not work.`  can you be more specific ? also, use `background-color` instead of `background` . It would be more suitable in your current situation, but that shouldn't cause a problem.

Comment: @Asturion here is the website deployed: https://wonderwoman-page.netlify.app/ 
I wonder if Foundation might disrupt something. Rifkan Razak's option works on other projects but not on this one.

Comment: @SashaB  you have errors in console releated to scripts. please clear them by deleting unnecessary <scripts> duplicates

Comment: also please combine all needed after documnet ready scripts under one $(document).ready(function()

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a class and call it, Check below example

```js
var navbar = document.querySelector('nav')
  window.onscroll = function() {

  // pageYOffset or scrollY
  if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
    navbar.classList.add('scrolled')
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove('scrolled')
  }
}
```

```css
 nav {
        position: -webkit-sticky;
        position: sticky;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        height: 80px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #ffa5001f;
      }

      nav.scrolled {
        background: orange;
      }

      main {
        height: 200vh;
      }
```

```html
   <nav></nav>
<main></main>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
 $('.navbar').attr('style', 'background: blue!important');
```