# Change border color on scroll

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change bottom border color of navigation bar on scroll down and change on scroll up. It should be smooth transition. For reference you can see Facebook messenger navigation bar border color (https://www.messenger.com/). I don't want to use any plugins (scroll trigger etc). It should be in pure java script and CSS from scratch.

**MY NAVBAR CSS CODE**

```
.nav {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 9999;
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
background-color: white;
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="nav">
</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking us to finish your code? This is not how it works.

Comment: you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66077768/jquery-change-background-color-on-scroll/66078608#66078608

Comment: I don’t think he/she is using jquery

Comment: Could you show us any Javascript code you have tried so far, perhaps linking to the scroll event

Comment: If you inspect that site that you have referenced - look in the console at the "event listeners window and check the scroll event listener. You can get teh exactcode they are using. Its a simple onScroll - then check amount of scroll and compare against a previous value and then alter the opacity of the div that is in the header  and has the bottom border styling.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it's pure javascript just add a class using JS, work as add and remove class.

```js
//use window.scrollY
var scrollpos = window.scrollY;
var header = document.getElementsByClassName("nav")[0];

function add_class_on_scroll() {
    header.classList.add("nav-border");
}

function remove_class_on_scroll() {
    header.classList.remove("nav-border");
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){ 
    //Here you forgot to update the value
    scrollpos = window.scrollY;

    if(scrollpos > 100){
        add_class_on_scroll();
    }
    else {
        remove_class_on_scroll();
    }
    console.log(scrollpos);
});
```

```css
.nav-border{
  border-bottom-color: red;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}
```

Comment: This is not "pure javascript" as you are using jQuery.

Comment: Now its Ready? if ready up my vote. hehehe

Comment: I just edited the answer to fix that - but I struggle with the idea of setting the variable as "header" when it is the "nav" element. You should always try to use approapriate and logical names for your classes and ids... what happens when there is an actual header in the code - now you wiill have the <header> element and the div.nav with a class of "header"...... poor form

Comment: Yes brother, i don't see i'd used jQuery sorry, but now used pure JS

Comment: Don’t know if it is just me as I am on a iPad, but it is not working

Comment: @theknightD2 it's not just the iPad. The snippet doesn't work on anything as it is incomplete (e.g. doesn't have the HTML and some of the original CSS). However, even if it were complete it does not sense scrolling up or down as requested in the question.

Comment: Ok. I see. @ArsKhatri please note