# Change the background color when scrolling in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I am trying is that when entering the web, the header has a defined background color and that when scrolling in the page X pixels, this background color changes color:

I have tried to copy several examples that I have found but they don't work either, and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I have this but it doesn't work for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script>
        $(function(){
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('header').addClass("azul");
                } else {
                $("header").removeClass("azul");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <header class="fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark ">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                  
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                          </a>
                          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                  </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <img class="botella" src="botella.png" alt="">
        <div id="uno">
            <div id="cambio"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="dos">
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
header {
    background-color: black;
}

header.azul {
    background-color: blue!important;
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66077768/jquery-change-background-color-on-scroll) answer your question? Also check this explanation of [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) out

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your scroll listener is never executed. With `$(document).ready()` You execute the function passed, whenever the page is loaded and ready.

```js
// Change the next line
        $(function(){
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('header').addClass("azul");
                } else {
                $("header").removeClass("azul");
                }
            });
        });
// into this line
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(window).scroll(function(){
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('header').addClass("azul");
                } else {
                $("header").removeClass("azul");
                }
            });
        });
```